# PowerShell & cURL - Get JSON Response and Check HTTP Response Code

Tags: powershell, curl

I have the following PowerShell script:

```
$CURLEXE = 'C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe'
$URL1 = "Example.com"

$GetTokenCurl = '-s', '-v', '-X', 'POST',
    $URL1,
    '-H', 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    '-d', 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=12345678&client_secret=abcdefgh',
    '--retry', '2', 
    '--retry-connrefused',
    '--retry-delay', '3'

Write-Host "Command took" (Measure-Command {$GetTokenResponse = & $CURLEXE @GetTokenCurl}).TotalSeconds "Seconds"

$GetTokenJSON = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $GetTokenResponse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$SessionToken = $GetTokenJSON.access_token
$AuthBearer = "Authorization: Bearer " + $SessionToken
```

It gets my Access Token from the SSO server and stores it into the $AuthBearer variable so I can reuse it for later scripts.

My response looks something like this:

```
{"access_token":"987654321","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600}
```

I am trying to also validate the HTTP response code from the server, which I have only been able to do (so far) by enabling `-v` (verbose) output. I am specifically looking for the HTTP response code after `< HTTP/1.1` (i.e. **200**). I can see this in the Verbose output:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

I can't for the life of me find a way to store the JSON response in a variable **and** check the contents of the Verbose output.

I've tried and failed to write the Verbose output to a text file.
I've tried the following two switches, but these mess up my JSON response:

```
-i, --include       Include protocol response headers in the output
-I, --head          Show document info only
```

I also tried the `--output` to a file, but that just wrote my JSON response and not the Verbose response to a file:

```
--output <file> Write to file instead of stdout
```

Is it possible using PowerShell and cURL to get the JSON response **and** check for the HTTP response code?

Comment: `curl` writes the regular output to STDOUT and the verbose (status) output to STDERR. You can separate these 2 streams as described in the answers to the linked question. Personally, I'd recommend going with the one provided by Aaron Schultz.

Comment: "Is it possible using PowerShell and cURL to get the JSON response and check for the HTTP response code?" Yes. I found this to work `curl  -X GET "..." -w "status:%{http_code}"` will give both the response and the status code. To suppress the response do "-o null" see: --write-out option for curl for more info.